# Requisição ajax não está funcionando

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

estou tendo problemas para fazer uma requisição via ajax.
A ideia é que ao sair no campo e-mail seja feita uma verificação no banco de dados se há ou não um e-mail igual registrado, porém se eu uso o "dataType: 'json'" ele não funciona. Fuciona apenas com "dataType: 'html'".
Agradeço se alguém souber me dizer o porquê disso.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Consulta de Email</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='email.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" class="form1" method="post">
        <label>email:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>

            <br /><br />

        <label>senha:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="senha" id="senha"/>

            <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Salvar Dados" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

email.js:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#email').blur(function(){
           $.ajax({
                url : 'consultar_email.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data: 'email=' + $('#email').val(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.cadastrado == true){
                        alert("email já cadastrado");
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("email não cadastrado");
                    }
                }
           });
           return false;    
   })
});
```

consultar_email.php

```
<?php
include_once("Classes/dadosDoBanco.php");
$cliente = new DadosCliente();

$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente"; 
$totalReg = $cliente->totalRegistros($sql);

for($i=0;$i<$totalReg;$i++)
{
    $cliente->verDados($sql, $i);
    $email2 = $cliente->getEmail();

    if($email == $email2)
    {
        $dados['cadastrado'] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $dados['cadastrado'] = false;
    }
}

echo json_encode($dados);
?>
```

Comment: Na linha data: 'email=' + $('#email').val(). Altere para data: {'email': $('#email').val()}

Comment: @touchmx da forma que estava ele funciona, o que ta dando problema é o dataType: 'json', eu acabei de trocar por dataType: 'html' e funcionou certinho, saberia me dizer o motivo?

Comment: Se você der um `alert(data.cadastrado)` qual é o retorno?

Comment: o problema é que ele não chega a passar pela parte $.ajax, e não chama o outro arquivo.

Comment: Seu código não aparenta erro. Na sua página **consultar_email.php** deixe apenas `echo json_encode( array('cadastrado' => false) );` para ver se há algum erro escapando no PHP antes de retornar o json.

Comment: não apresenta, eu já testei essa parte sem chama-la através do ajax, e funciona como deveria

Comment: @Vinícius já testou `data: {email: $('#email').val(),` em vez de `data: 'email=' + $('#email').val(),` como foi sugerido aqui?

Comment: @Sergio sim, já testei, porém desta forma não funciona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara, o código só funciona quando você seta o `dataType` como html porque no seu php você esta retornando `html` ao invés de json, vou explicar...

por mais que no seu `php` você esteja retornando um:

```
echo json_encode($dados);
```

Você não setou um Header, se você abrir o inspector do seu browser e ver o `http-response-header` da sua requisição, verá que ela esta retornando um `content-type: text/html`

Para corrigir este problema, antes do seu retorno no `php`, você deve setar o header como json, assim :

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($dados);
```

Answer (score 4):

O problema não é ao enviar o dado para o server, pois o jQuery envia por padrão os dados com o mimeType `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, que é o correto para o método POST.

O dataType é utilizado pelo jQuery para determinar como tratar o resultado do request. No seu caso `json` deveria funcionar. Como você não postou o erro que está ocorrendo fica difícil de dizer o motivo.

Eu chutaria que o jQuery está identificando de forma errada o tipo do retorno da request quando você coloca `json`. Tente setar o `Content-Type` no PHP para `application/json`, pois o jQuery usa essa informação para descobrir qual o tipo do retorno.

Comment: eu fiz o código igual a [este](http://www.rafaelwendel.com/2012/08/preenchimento-automatico-do-endereco-a-partir-do-cep/) e tive o msm problema, ele nem chega a fazer a requisição ajax

Comment: Mas qual o erro? Não aparece nada no console do Chrome?

Comment: não acusa nenhum erro

Comment: O problema é de javascript então. Se você colocar um alert antes do $.ajax, aparece algo?

Comment: aparece, mas após isso não

Comment: Algum erro está ocorrendo dentro do $.ajax do JQuery. Utilize a opção error para identificar o problema. Sugiro você debugar via Developer Tools do Chrome.

Comment: tentarei, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Quanto você define um valor para dataType, o tipo escolhido deve ser usado tanto para valor enviado pelo ajax no campo "data" como para o valor retornado pelo php, que no seu caso e json.

Tenta fazer assim:

```
$.ajax({
     url : 'consultar_email.php',
     type : 'POST',
     data: {"email":$('#email').val()}, //Alterado como JSON
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data){
        if(data.cadastrado == true){
           alert("email já cadastrado");
        }
        else{
           alert("email não cadastrado");
        }
     }
});
```

Obs.: Não esquece de retornar um JSON do PHP

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se é o seu caso também mas tive um problema parecido quando alterei a versão do PHP no Wamp para 7.2, normalmente eu uso o PHP5.6 ou PHP 7.1, um dia alterei para o 7.4 para fazer uns teste em um projeto novo e não passava pelo $.ajax de jeito nenhum, quando lembrei que tinha mudado a versão do PHP voltei para o PHP 7.1 e voltou a funcinar normal.

Answer (score -3):

Vinícius não sei se você resolveu o seu problema depois de muito tempo. Tenta definir as variáveis colocando uma condicional if(isset($_POST)) OU if(isset($_GET) sem informar o name