# JSON NAO RETORNA

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Estou a fazer um update no banco de dados. Mas o json nao retorna. Podem ajudar-me por favor?

ARQUIVO JQUERY

```
 $(document).ready(function($) {

 // Evento Submit do formulário
 $('#myForm').submit(function() {

  // Captura os dados do formulário
  var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

  // Instância o FormData passando como parâmetro o formulário
  var formData = new FormData(myForm);

  // Envia O FormData através da requisição AJAX
  $.ajax({
     url: "update_func.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: formData,
     dataType: "JSON",
     processData: false,  
     contentType: false,
     success: function(retorno){
       if (retorno.status == 1){
        alertigo(retorno.mensagem, {color: 'light-blue'});        
       }else{
        alertigo(retorno.mensagem, {color: 'red'});
        //$('.mensagem').html(retorno.mensagem);
       }
        }
  });

  return false;
 });

});
```

ARQUIVO PHP

```
    <?php 
 $panel_atual = "funcionario";

 require "../config.php";

 $retorno= array();

 $id = intval($_POST['id_func']);
 $nome =  $_POST['nome'];
 $naturalidade =  $_POST['naturalidade'];
 $residente =  $_POST['residente'];
 $description =  $_POST['description'];
 $imgvar_func = $_FILES['img']['name']; 

 if (file_exists("img_func/$imgvar_func")) {
  $a = 1;
  while (file_exists("img_func/[$a]$imgvar_func")) {
    $a++;
   }
   $imgvar_func = "[".$a."]".$imgvar_func;
 }



 $result_edit = "UPDATE funcionarios SET naturalidade='$naturalidade', residente='$residente', description = '$description', imagem = '$imgvar_func' WHERE nome='$nome' AND  id='$id'";


 $retorno = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_edit); 

 (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], "img_func/".$imgvar_func));



 if($retorno){
  $retorno = array('status' => 1, 'mensagem' => 'REGISTRO INSERIDO COM SUCESSO!');

 }
 else{
  $retorno = array('status' => 0, 'mensagem' => 'ERRO AO INSERIR REGISTRO!');

 }
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

Comment: Coloque todo o código relevante, por exemplo o html do form, nome das páginas

Comment: mas retornar algum erro? Sugiro implementar o bloco de erro do `$ajax` para ver se está retornando erro: `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { ... } `

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Requisição ajax não está funcionando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37819/requisi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ajax-n%c3%a3o-est%c3%a1-funcionando)

Comment: Tente setar o header
 header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($dados);

Comment: Mas retorno de update seria somente true ou false não ?